# Sed usage, remove / change text

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have an string that generated as following

```
OK::82.44.127.13:GB:UNITED KINGDOM:ENGLAND:WOKING:-:51.000:-0.55813:+01:00
```

i need a sed string to basically change to

```
82.44.127.13;GB UNITED KINGDOM ENGLAND WOKING;51.000;-0.55813
```

i think this will require multi runs of sed, so far i have:

```
sed 's/:-:/;/g' (which will change the :-: to a ;)
sed 's/:-/;-/g' (which will change the :- to a ;)
sed s/OK:://g  (which will strip the OK::)
```

but im stuck on how to change the : between the ip address and location to a ;, and then remove all other :, and also strip off the time?

(note not really ip addresses)

Comment: Two hints for you. You can use multiple commands in a single sed run. (eg `sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/bar/baz/'` or `sed -e 's/foo/bar/;s/bar/baz/'` etc.) The second being that you can probably do this with `cut` instead.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` it can be easier:

```
$ awk -F ":" '{print $3";"$4" "$5" "$6" "$7";"$9";"$10}' <<< "OK::82.44.127.13:GB:UNITED KINGDOM:ENGLAND:WOKING:-:51.000:-0.55813:+01:00"
82.44.127.13;GB UNITED KINGDOM ENGLAND WOKING;51.000;-0.55813
```

Note that I am printing things like `$3";"$4" "$5` because the field separator is changing. Otherwise we could use: `BEGIN{OFS=";"}`

```
$ awk -F ":" 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}{print $3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$9,$10}' <<< "OK::82.44.127.13:GB:UNITED KINGDOM:ENGLAND:WOKING:-:51.000:-0.55813:+01:00"
82.44.127.13;GB;UNITED KINGDOM;ENGLAND;WOKING;51.000;-0.55813
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do everything in one sed command:

```
$ echo "OK::82.44.127.13:GB:UNITED KINGDOM:ENGLAND:WOKING:-:51.000:-0.55813:+01:00" | \
sed -r 's/OK::([0-9.]*):([A-Z ]*):([A-Z ]*):([A-Z ]*):([A-Z ]*):-:(-?[0-9.]*):(-?[0-9.]*):.*/\1;\2 \3 \4 \5;\6;\7/'
82.44.127.13;GB UNITED KINGDOM ENGLAND WOKING;51.000;-0.55813
```

Answer (score 1):

Without awk:

```
cut -d: -f 3-7,9,10  | tr ":" ";" | sed -r 's/([A-Z]);([A-Z])/\1 \2/g'
```